How were Jewish communities in Babylon affected by the revolts of Nebuchadnezzar III and IV against Darius I?
I'm researching the impact of the Babylonian revolts against Persian rule (522-521 BCE) on the Jewish population living in Babylon during this period. Specifically, I'm interested in how the Jewish communities were affected during the rebellions of Nidintu-Bēl (Nebuchadnezzar III) and Arakha (Nebuchadnezzar IV) against Darius I.
What we know:
Many Jews remained in Babylon after Cyrus's decree allowing return to Jerusalem
Nebuchadnezzar III controlled central Babylon for a while
Nebuchadnezzar IV's revolt occurred sometime after that first rebellion was squashed
Jews generally favored Persian rule according to biblical and extrabiblical sources
Some scholars (like Galling in VT, II 1952) suggest that certain passages in Zechariah may reflect Jewish anxiety during these revolts, particularly due to their previous support of Persian authority.
Specific questions I'm seeking to answer:
Is there evidence of how these Jewish communities were treated during these revolts?
Did their generally pro-Persian stance affect their treatment by the rebel leaders?
Are there any contemporary sources (Persian, Babylonian, or Jewish) that document their situation?
